# No matching distribution found for torch==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))

Tags: python

No matching distribution found for torch==1.0.0

I was instructed to use to use pytorch==1.0.0 for training. Higher versions of pytorch have strange bilinear warping behavior, because of it model diverge. but i cannot install it from requirement.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try looking here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#v100

This answer may not help at all, I don't know a ton about how requirement.txt files work. However, I do know that you can make a new environment and install older versions, commands are given at the website I gave above.